# How to run bash commands and leave prompt open?

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash function that will run some commands to setup the environment and then leave the user at the prompt.

I can run

```
bash -c 'ls'
```

To execute `ls` in bash.

I can also do

```
bash -c 'ls ; exec bash'
```

To execute `ls`, and then leave a bash prompt open.

However, I want to source a file and setup some aliases, functions, and environment variables and then leave the prompt open, so something like this:

```
 bash -c 'source env.sh ; exec bash'
```

Of course, this doesn't work because subshells will not inherit aliases or functions. Is there a way around this problem? I'd prefer to still have the user's `.bashrc` be sourced, and not use the `--init-file` option.

Comment: This looks like reinventing the wheel.  What you describe is the *exact* purpose of the init file.

Comment: What's the point of not using the `--init-file` option?

Comment: Hmm, it was moreso that I wanted to avoid cluttering my computer with init files. I was writing some helper functions to initialized my Android setup (which requires switching my shell to `bash` and sourcing some files). Making a new file seemed excessive when I only needed to execute around 5 lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up an init file that will source the user's init file at the start, and then do whatever else you want:

```
$ cat env.sh
. ~/.bashrc
export SOMEVAR="value"
somespecialfunction() {
  printf '%s\n' "I'm so cool"
}
$ bash --init-file env.sh
```

Comment: After more thought this seems fine for what I'm doing. I can pass environment variables as arguments to the init file. Thanks!