# How to run a command in Git-Bash and leave the shell running?

Tags: bash

I have started from this question: [How to run bash commands and leave prompt open?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317837/how-to-run-bash-commands-and-leave-prompt-open)

However, apparently, `bash` and `Git-Bash` are quite different.
`Git-Bash` is a wrapper that behaves differently.

I have a shortcut that starts this `Git-Bash` shell. After starting it, I want it to `source start.sh` automatically, and then to leave the shell open.

[image: The Short-Cut]

[image: The Properties of the Short-Cut]

Whatever I have tried so far did not work.

This is my `start.sh` Shell-Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The File-Editor.
alias n='"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"'

# The Build Commands.
alias gp='/c/DGSante/Git/dg-sante-new-cpms/gp.sh'

# The 'Docker' Commands.
alias dd='docker-compose down -v'
alias db='docker-compose build'
alias du='docker-compose up'
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks everyone for commenting.

This is an example of one of my attempts to solve this problem:

The shortcut starts the following one-liner:

`/c/Progra~1/Git/git-bash.exe -c 'exec /c/Progra~1/Git/git-bash.exe --cd=/c/DGSante/Git/dg-sante-new-cpms/ --init-file /c/DGSante/Git/dg-sante-new-cpms/start.sh -i'`

However, although the first `Git-Bash` interactively starts the second `Git-Bash` in the necessary working folder and uses the `start.sh` as an `init-file`, the secondary `Git-Bash` is terminated and it does not remain open.

**SOLUTION:**

Great thanks to @muru for clarifications.

The working solution looks like the following one-liner:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --cd=C:\DGSante\Git\dg-sante-new-cpms\ --init-file C:\DGSante\Git\dg-sante-new-cpms\start.sh
```

I have removed the usage of the `Git-Bash` wrapper. I am relying entirely on the `Bash` port to the `Microsoft` `Windows` Operating-System.

I absolutely agree to @Marcus Müller's comments. However, this is the only place where I have found help.

Thanks everyone.

**RESULT:**

[image: The Shell with its sourced Script]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far? How did you configure Git Bash to source this file at startup?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is explicitly *not* about a shell running on Linux/UNIX, but about a shell running on Windows.

Comment: (asking this here is like asking here why firefox on windows misbehaves in a Windows-specific way: though firefox, just as bash, are natively available for UNIX systems, the problems here are specific to a concrete version for Windows. You're just reaching the wrong community here)

Comment: aliases typically don't work in non-interactive shells such as scripts.  From `man bash`: *"Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the `expand_aliases` shell option is set using `shopt`"*

Comment: You probably need something like `/c/Progra~1/Git/git-bash.exe --cd=/c/DGSante/Git/dg-sante-new-cpms/  -c 'exec bash --init-file /c/DGSante/Git/dg-sante-new-cpms/start.sh'`

Comment: If you want, you can post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by @muru, maybe it is a good idea to write the answer to this question here.

This does not solve the `Git-Bash` problem, however.

It is just a workaround that is based on the `Bash` port to the `Microsoft` `Windows` Operating-System.

The following one-liner *does* start the Shell, which executes the Shell-Script, and also leaves the terminal running:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --cd=C:\DGSante\Git\dg-sante-new-cpms\ --init-file C:\DGSante\Git\dg-sante-new-cpms\start.sh
```

Comment: By "Bash port to the Microsoft Windows Operating-System" do you mean the Windows Subsystem for Linux? It doesn't look like you're using WSL here

Comment: You are right, @muru. I also have the *Microsoft* *Windows Subsystem for Linux*, but this `bash.exe` executable is described in its properties as `Git for Windows`. Also, in its details, the original filename is marked as `git.exe`. The product name is `Git`, with the file version `2.41.0.1`, and with the product version `2.41.0.windows.1`. So, I guess that this is actually still `Git-Bash`, but not the wrapper itself.